# tsc compiles ES6 code into ES5

Tags: typescript, ecmascript-6, tsc

'I am using TS 2.2 and I tried compiling my ES6 module ( js file) using tsc and it did compile into valid ES5 code. I was using google's Tracur OR some other tool int he past to do so. I believe, this feature, of compiling js files from ES6 to ES5, was not part of tsc compiler.  Has this been added in the new TS versions??
I tried looking into the changes in tsc but did not find this feature been added.
Does anyone knows, when this feature has been added ??

Following is my test.js file,

```
function Add(...numberArr){

       let result = 0;

       numberArr.forEach((n) => result += n);

        return result;

   }
```

compiled file with tsc looks below,

```
"use strict";
function Add() {
    var numberArr = [];
    for (var _i = 0; _i < arguments.length; _i++) {
        numberArr[_i] = arguments[_i];
    }
    var result = 0;
    numberArr.forEach(function (n) { return result += n; });
    return result;
}
```

**Note:** We need to set the **AllowJS** flag to **true** in the **tsconfig.json** file to take advantage of this feature though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

typescript always had an embedded transpiler, you probably haven't noticed.

Comment: Note: [--allowJs appeared in 1.8](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What%27s-new-in-TypeScript#including-js-files-with---allowjs)